# Unable to call a HTTP POST request having a csv file more than 10000 records

Tags: c#, csv, http-post

I am calling a Web API from my C# code wherein I am making an HTTPPost request and sending a CSV file containing almost 11000 rows/records.
It works fine when the number of rows is less than 10,000. However, it throws a 400 bad request when records exceed 10,000.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sending CSV file to WEB API? Or holding the CSV data into one object and then send it to the WEB API?

Comment: holding csv data in an object alongwith auth key, content type and other info

Comment: Do not call API with the whole 10,000 records, instead create a bunch of the 20-30 records and call the API.

Comment: we have a third party view created to fetch the records from sql server, hence cant make any changes there. This result set needs to be converted into a csv and then send to the third party API. These records needs to be uploaded at once as further processing needs to be done from third party side.

Answer (score 0):

If Web API is hosted by IIS, the default upload file size is 4MB.

To increase that limit, you could update web.config settings:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" /> <!-- KB -->
</system.web>

<!-- for IIS 7+ -->
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!-- Byte -->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: No, this is a third party WebAPI which we have to communicate with,

Comment: My csv file is coming out to be only 1.55 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue. It seems there was no issue with my code to POST the records. It was third party WebAPI's restriction to upload at max 10,000 records.